# Clarification on node setup when applying surface imperfection

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to understand shading and nodes and would appreciate it if someone could just confirm that I have understood correctly, and I also have a question.

Currently, I am experimenting with adding surface imperfections and following this example:

Link: https://cdn2.cgbookcase.cloud/textures/guides/blender/surface%20imperfections/dirt_setup.jpg

My question is, what is the purpose of the value node in the example?

If I understand correctly, Color 1/A should be my roughness map, and completely black should mean no roughness, and vice versa if I want roughness, it should be completely white.

With Fac set to 0, only Color1/A is present. Fac set to 1 becomes A+B with Screen.

But in the example, what is the purpose of the value node that is used? Is it simply setting the Value to 0.03 in HSV? So if I have 0.03 in Value in HSV, will I get the same result as with the Value node?"

[image]

[image: HSV]

Comment: If it is not used as a driver for some field, it has absolutely no use because it is not plugged in anywhere.

Comment: Its plugged into in the example I was following: https://cdn2.cgbookcase.cloud/textures/guides/blender/surface%20imperfections/dirt_setup.jpg In my picture if have disconnected it and used a value instead.

Comment: Well, when asking if it is of any use you should show a screenshot where it is actually in use. In this case, plugging a float into a vector input (a color input is like a vector) will set the float in all three channels. So with RGB having all the same float, it is basically as you suspect, creating an RGB color with (0.03, 0.03, 0.03) which corresponds to an HSV color with a saturation of 0 and a value of 0.03

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify what a float is, and I though Vector was a Normal. But im new to this, so could you help to explain that?

Comment: These are not Blender-specific terms. Generally, a float is a single decimal number (a *scalar*), vectors are quantities which cannot be expressed by a single scalar, like normals or directions etc., they can be expressed by an $n$-dimensional vector, where $n$ is the number of scalars they contain. In Blender vectors are usually 3-dimensional, holding an X, Y and Z value. But RGB colors are 3-dimensional vectors, too, only that you call the dimensions here R, G and B. That's just a quick explanation, not meant to be mathematically 100% accurately phrased but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: By the way, the _Screen_ mode in the _Color Mix_ node does not become $A+B$ when you set the mix factor to 1, it becomes $1-(1-B)(1-A)$, because the formula is $$1-((1-Fac)+Fac\cdot (1-B))\cdot (1-A)$$ which means, it will only be the same as $A+B$ when one or both values are 0.

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand what you mean, could you explain it in a easier manner?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149698/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-n03).